# In angular how to bind model with value of null or undefined or empty string to option in select?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have variable called `model`. This variable can be `null` or `undefined` or empty string or valid with value: a string or object.

```
 class .. { 
   model = null // undefined or '' or 'bla'
 }
```

The select is bind to this `model` variable: `[(ngModel)]="model"`.

In the select there are some options and one option is `select..` (with no value).

What I want is: If the `model` is `null` or `undefined` or empty string - the `select` control will select the first option (without value).

```
 <select [(ngModel)]="model">
  <option>select something...</option>
  <option value="1">op-1</option>
  <option value="2">op-2</option>
 </select>
```

When I set the option with value of `null` and the `model` is null, then it match the option of `select something`:

```
 <option [value]="null">..
```

But when the model is changing to `undefined` then nothing is match- and what I want is to match the `select something...`.

So I was thinking to do my own version of [`option` directive](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5d11844a7c31df56d2b97e3aa6cd1a70b5fccc70/packages/forms/src/directives/select_control_value_accessor.ts#L174) and copy the behavior of `option` when setting the value.

The problem is I try to set the value but it doesn't change as excepted.

```
    this._renderer.setProperty(this._element.nativeElement, 'value', ''); // null/undefiend/''
```

Any idea how to make this work?

Here my code I try to play with:

```
@Directive({ selector: '[ngxValue]', standalone: true })
export class NgSelectOption implements OnDestroy {
  /**
   * @description
   * ID of the option element
   */
  // TODO(issue/24571): remove '!'.
  id!: string;

  constructor(
    private _element: ElementRef,
    private _renderer: Renderer2,
    @Optional() @Host() private _select: SelectControlValueAccessor
  ) {
    if (this._select) this.id = (this._select as any)._registerOption();
  }

  // @Input('ngValue')
  // set ngValue(value: any) {
  //   if (this._select == null) return;
  //   this._select._optionMap.set(this.id, value);
  //   this._setElementValue(_buildValueString(this.id, value));
  //   this._select.writeValue(this._select.value);
  // }

  // @Input('value')
  // set value(value: any) {
  //   this._setElementValue(value);
  //   if (this._select) this._select.writeValue(this._select.value);
  // }

  @Input('ngxValue')
  set ngxValue(value: any) {
    console.log({ value });
    this._renderer.setProperty(this._element.nativeElement, 'value', '');
  }

  /** @internal */
  _setElementValue(value: string): void {
    this._renderer.setProperty(this._element.nativeElement, 'value', value);
  }

  /** @nodoc */
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this._select) {
      (this._select as any)._optionMap.delete(this.id);
      this._select.writeValue(this._select.value);
    }
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, NgSelectOption],
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{name}}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.io/start">
      Learn more about Angular 
    </a><br>
    <select [(ngModel)]="model_undefined">
     <option disabled ngxValue>select something...</option>
     <option [value]="1">op1</option>
    </select>
    model_undefined: {{model_undefined|json}}
    <br>
    <select [(ngModel)]="model_null">
     <option disabled ngxValue>select something...</option>
     <option [value]="1">op1</option>
    </select>
    model_null: {{model_null|json}}
    <br>
    <select [(ngModel)]="model_empty_string">
     <option disabled ngxValue>select something...</option>
     <option [value]="1">op1</option>
    </select>
    model_empty_string: {{model_empty_string|json}}
    <br>
    <select [(ngModel)]="mode_with_value">
     <option disabled ngxValue>select something...</option>
     <option [value]="1">op1</option>
    </select>
    mode_with_value: {{mode_with_value|json}}

  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  model_undefined = undefined;
  model_null = null;
  model_empty_string = '';
  mode_with_value = '1';
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-djad7e?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: You need [`[ngValue]`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/apps/ng-bootstrap-demo/src/app/pages/basic/forms/select/select.component.html#L11) - [Demo](https://bootstrap.mintplayer.com/basic/forms/select)

Comment: [Here's](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#using-select-controls-in-a-template-driven-form) more information

Answer (score 1):

P.S. I'm adding 3 possible ways to solve your issue (as I understand it) here :

1. Custom control ("the angular way")
2. Multiple mutually hiding options for the empty values ("the quickest hack that works well and fast if you need it in a pinch")
3. Structural directive ("the angular pros that write libraries way")

---

You probably want a custom form control here, as a idiomatic solution. [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-nndjfh)'s a working example, but the main idea is this:

1. You create a custom component that implements Angular's `ControlValueAccessor`.
2. Within it, you just have a normal select like any other. But how you communicate to the outside world is via the Forms API.
3. There, you'd convert all the "empty" values to something custom - but when giving that value back out to Angular, you find the actual, hidden version of the value.

The key part is the custom form control, something like this:

```
// Let us have something to store "empty" values.
const MY_EMPTY_VALUE = Symbol.for('my empty value.');

@Component({
  selector: 'my-select',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
  <select
  [ngModel]="myInternalValue"
  (ngModelChange)="onInternalChange($event)"
  [disabled]="isDisabled"
>
  <option [value]="MY_EMPTY_VALUE">{{ emptyValueLabel }}</option>
  <option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.value">
    {{ option.label }}
  </option>
</select>

  `,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => MySelectComponent),
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
  imports: [FormsModule, CommonModule],
})
export class MySelectComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input() emptyValueLabel = 'Please select option';

  @Input() options: Array<{
    value: unknown;
    label: string;
  }> = [];

  // Here the component users can tell us which values they consider "empty".
  @Input() emptyValues: unknown[] = [null, undefined, '', false];

  // We need this on the instance so that the form can match.
  MY_EMPTY_VALUE = MY_EMPTY_VALUE.toString();

  // The value we'll keep internally is kinda like T, but we also include our unique "empty" symbol.
  myInternalValue: unknown = null;

  isDisabled = false;

  onChange!: (value: unknown) => undefined;
  onTouched!: () => undefined;

  // Angular gives us a callback with which to tell it when we think our form value has changed
  registerOnChange(fn: (value: unknown) => undefined): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  // Angular gives us a callback with which to tell it when we think our custom control is "touched"
  registerOnTouched(fn: () => undefined): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  // If the form control gets disabled (or enabled again), Angular calls this.
  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.isDisabled = isDisabled;
  }

  // Angular tells us the "users" of the component wrote some value, e.g. programmatically setting the ngModel.
  writeValue(value: unknown): void {
    console.log('Writing value from outside:', value);
    if (this.emptyValues.includes(value)) {
      this.myInternalValue = MY_EMPTY_VALUE.toString();
    } else {
      this.myInternalValue = value;
    }
  }

  onInternalChange(value: unknown) {
    console.log('Sending new value outside.');
    this.myInternalValue = value;
    this.onChange(value);
    this.onTouched();
  }
}
```

Note: I think I didn't get the Symbol uniqueness magic correctly (cause of that toString call) but approximately this would be the answer.

This is a nice and quick component, it scales relatively well (meaning, you can extend it with no issues, up to a point) and it does the job well.

---

Another alternative would be to be a little hacky - it's working and it's faster, but it's not as portable (you'd have to copy-paste it frequently):

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="myModel">
  <option *ngIf="ngModel === undefined" [value]="undefined">Select value here</option>
  <option *ngIf="ngModel === null" [value]="null">Select value here</option>
  <option *ngIf="ngModel === ''" value="">Select value here</option>
  <option [value]="a">a</option>
  <option [value]="b">b</option>
</select>
```

The reason this works is that we're actually having multiple options, and hiding the non-metching ones. [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jww7xs)'s *that* version in action.

The downside is that you potentially have repaints or even flicker, depending on your styling, browsers etc. most likely it's gonna be fine though.

---

If you wanted, you could probably make this second version into a custom directive. Except, it'd have to be a *structural* directive. The kind that customly creates and destroys elements. Kinda like how *ngIf or *ngFor can create things out of thin air. Means, you have an option for an empty value, but you also tell it it's *structural* which means it will provide other template values instead of just yours.

You would use it like this:

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="myModel">
  <option *myEmptyOption="myModel">Select value here</option>
  <option *ngIf="ngModel === null" [value]="null">Select value here</option>
  <option *ngIf="ngModel === ''" value="">Select value here</option>
  <option [value]="a">a</option>
  <option [value]="b">b</option>
</select>
```

The critical part of the directive itself would look like this:

```
@Input() set emptyOptionValue(value: unknown) {
  if (value === null || value === undefined || value === '') {
    // you'd make your empty option selected here
  } else {
    // you'd make your empty option deselected here
  }
}
```

I don't have a stackblitz for this one, but I hope you can get there on your own following on the examples from above.

Answer (score 0):

why not use?

```
 <option disabled hidden *ngFor="let option of [null,undefined,'']" 
          [ngValue]="option">select something...</option>
```

The "disabled hidden" makes that you can not selected (dont' appear in the options when you drop down) but show the "select something" if the value is null, undefined or ''